# WCF, Windows Store apps, and reliable sessions

Tags: wcf, windows-store-apps, reliablesession

Is it possible to use WCF reliable sessions in Windows Store apps?

I am writing a Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2012 Professional using C#.  I am trying to access a WCF service using sessions.  I can't use WSHttpBinding because Windows Store apps don't support it.  I found that Windows Store apps DO support NetHTTPBinding, which supports reliable sessions, but I can't seem to access the ReliableSession property of the binding, nor can I access the constructor that takes "bool reliableSessionEnabled" as a parameter.

Is there ANY binding that supports sessions for Windows Store apps?

-Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding.reliablesession.aspx) (Version Information section), `ReliableSession` property is not available for Windows Store apps, i.e. WCF reliable sessions are not supported.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx) describes the complete subset of WCF functionalities available in Windows Store apps. Although `NetHttpBinding` is included, `ReliableSessionBindingElement` is not.

Comment: Damir, I just looked a that page, and I don't see where it says that it's not available for Windows Store apps.  Under Version Information, all it says is, ".NET Framework Supported in: 4.5"

Comment: @JoeMjr2 Exactly, .NET for Windows Store apps is not .NET Framework 4.5. If you look at a property that is available for Windows Store apps, such as [TextEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.servicemodel.httpbindingbase.textencoding.aspx), it clearly says: ".NET for Windows Store apps Supported in: Windows 8".